# Lightning icon in lightning tab

Tags: lightning-tab, lightning-tabset, icon

I am trying to add an icon in tabs Labels of a lightning:tabset.

```
        <lightning:tabset   >
            <lightning:tab  >
                <aura:set attribute="label"  >
                    tab 1 
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevronup" />
                </aura:set>

                content tab 1

            </lightning:tab>

            <lightning:tab  >
                <aura:set attribute="label"  >
                    tab 2 
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:chevronup" />
                </aura:set>
                content tab 2
            </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
```

1. With this code the tabs displaying correctly but not the Icons.
2. If I use Ligtning tabset as it describe here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/specification ; 
   Is it possible to change size and color of the Icon. Is it possible to display the icon on condition ?

Comment: according to the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tab/specification  The attribute accepts string values, but for compatibility with previous releases also accepts a component type. Only the text portion of the label value displays so i dont think we can show icon by passing in label

Comment: I see , Thanks. I thought it was possible according to the response here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145734/how-to-use-slds-svg-icons-with-lightningtabset
 if not do you have any idea how could I set incon in the tab with condition an CSS ?

Comment: it was possible https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_lc_components.htm but if you see in winter19 docs they say they only accept text in label from now

Comment: it could be possible with slds-tabs but you have to build every functionality from base